# Firebase auth is called twice

Tags: swift, firebase

I am creating a simple app with Register / Login view controllers which lead to a TableView Controller.

Issues is that when I call the loginBtnPressed method, it seems the Auth.auth() is called twice because the print statement "Login for user..." is printed twice and performSegue is also executed twice.

Could some one help with whats going on?

Attaching the logs:

> 2019-03-25 13:13:50.299237+0530 countIT_Z[61176:7896870]  - [I-ACS036002] Analytics screen reporting is enabled. Call +[FIRAnalytics setScreenName:setScreenClass:] to set the screen name or override the default screen class name. To disable screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseScreenReportingEnabled to NO (boolean) in the Info.plist
>   2019-03-25 13:13:50.505813+0530 countIT_Z[61176:7896870] 5.18.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.50700000 started
>   2019-03-25 13:13:50.507465+0530 countIT_Z[61176:7896870] 5.18.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled ()
>   2019-03-25 13:13:51.043075+0530 countIT_Z[61176:7896954] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C1.1:2][0x7fb97370b740] get output frames failed, state 8196
>   2019-03-25 13:13:51.043302+0530 countIT_Z[61176:7896954] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C1.1:2][0x7fb97370b740] get output frames failed, state 8196
>   2019-03-25 13:13:51.044079+0530 countIT_Z[61176:7896954] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
>   2019-03-25 13:13:51.044260+0530 countIT_Z[61176:7896954] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
>   2019-03-25 13:13:53.550835+0530 countIT_Z[61176:7896752] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /Users/***/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/18BEEB16-AA64-48C6-B88D-FEF2CFA1EDA3/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
>   2019-03-25 13:13:53.552997+0530 countIT_Z[61176:7896752] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.
>   First
>   2019-03-25 13:13:59.763175+0530 countIT_Z[61176:7896969] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C2.1:2][0x7fb973502f00] get output frames failed, state 8196
>   2019-03-25 13:13:59.763425+0530 countIT_Z[61176:7896969] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C2.1:2][0x7fb973502f00] get output frames failed, state 8196
>   2019-03-25 13:13:59.764174+0530 countIT_Z[61176:7896969] TIC Read Status [2:0x0]: 1:57
>   2019-03-25 13:13:59.764619+0530 countIT_Z[61176:7896969] TIC Read Status [2:0x0]: 1:57
>   2019-03-25 13:14:00.422619+0530 countIT_Z[61176:7896953] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C4.1:2][0x7fb973714ae0] get output frames failed, state 8196
>   2019-03-25 13:14:00.423064+0530 countIT_Z[61176:7896953] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C4.1:2][0x7fb973714ae0] get output frames failed, state 8196
>   2019-03-25 13:14:00.423907+0530 countIT_Z[61176:7896953] TIC Read Status [4:0x0]: 1:57
>   2019-03-25 13:14:00.424707+0530 countIT_Z[61176:7896953] TIC Read Status [4:0x0]: 1:57
>   Login for user Optional("a@b.com") is successful
>   2019-03-25 13:14:01.101242+0530 countIT_Z[61176:7896752] [Warning] Warning once only: Detected a case where constraints ambiguously suggest a height of zero for a tableview cell's content view. We're considering the collapse unintentional and using standard height instead.

```
@IBAction func loginBtnPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let userEmailId = loginEmailIdTF.text
        let userPassword = loginPasswordTF.text

        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: userEmailId!, password: userPassword!) { (status, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Login error")
            } else {
                print("Login for user \(String(describing: userEmailId)) is successful")
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToAllCountersFromLogin", sender: self)
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: When you put a break-point inside the ```loginBtnPressed``` function, does it hit the break-point twice?

Comment: @Len_X - No it didn't and that pointed me to the issue. I had added the segue to the button itself, and was calling it again in loginBtnPressed. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest changing your method to this :

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { [weak self] user, error in
  guard let strongSelf = self else { 
    return 
  }
  // Do segue here 
}
```

Let me know if this works